# What is a committee looking for in a dissertation proposal?

Tags: phd, thesis, advisor

I've started narrowing down the scope of my dissertation, and I have one year before I need to defend my proposal.  I'm curious to know what is expected from a dissertation proposal.  What are the key elements that I should include / exclude?  What criteria typically used to judge whether the proposal defense is successful?  Are the committee's feedback of the proposal typically used as a criteria for the full fledged dissertation defense?

Comment: Only your committee can give you a definitive answer.  What does your advisor say?

Comment: Good advice here: http://matt.might.net/articles/advice-for-phd-thesis-proposals/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JeffE is correct; talk to your chair and get feedback. That being said, you'll want to include the following in your talk:

1. An overview of your research topic
2. A discussion of relevant literature (to demonstrate that you've researched the topic)
3. A discussion of your specific problem
4. Another literature discussion, much more focused on your specific problem
5. Any preliminary results of experiments you may have run, if any
6. What you plan on doing for the next few years
7. *(Possibly most important)* Any specific issues/problems that your advisors have raised about your research. You should specifically address these to show that you're paying attention to what they say and that you listen to their comments.

The best way to prepare is to talk with everyone in advance and find out what their objections/comments/issues/questions will be as much as possible, and then do your best to prepare for that and any related issues. If that sounds like a lot of work, it's because it is a lot of work.

Dan's comments are also spot on; you may have some very difficult committee members who will ask all sorts of questions, and you should make sure your advisor is on your side from the get-go.

Comment: Should one also have partial or preliminary results to present as well?

Comment: Good point; I added it. Do make sure, though, that you have something to *propose*; I have a friend who tried to present his completed thesis work at his proposal, and got a lot of extra work because of it.

Comment: So, are you saying that one should hold back if you already have lots of results?  Is this a good strategy?

Comment: @Paul - No, I'm saying that you should make sure to do your proposal before you complete all your experiments. It isn't really relevant to the question, and it shouldn't be an issue for most people.

Answer (score 13):

Ultimately, **your committee has total say about what constitutes a successful thesis proposal**.  As JeffE mentioned, you should **ask them** (particularly your chair).  In my case, I scheduled short meetings (10-20 minutes) with each of my committee members.  (Ideally, this should happen at least 3 before your proposal.)  I asked each one **"What are you looking for in my thesis [proposal] for you to judge it as successful?"**  I don't remember all of their answers. From three of the four members of my committee (including my chair) I had clear expectations, which I knew I could meet.

Sadly, from one member, I never really got a clear answer.  Not surprisingly (in retrospect), part way through my presentation he complained because he thought that what I was presenting was off-topic.  In the end, everything was okay.  However, I think he was a bit unhappy and had to be *persuaded* to pass me.  The **single most important thing you can do to guarantee a successful proposal (or defense) is to make sure that your chair will strongly support you if you get resistance from another committee member**.  Besides that, you should schedule meetings (as I mentioned above) to ask what your committee is looking for.  Start with your chair and get advice from him/her about how to approach your other members.  If you don't get a good answer from one member, try scheduling another meeting to ask again (perhaps after meeting with your chair a second time to ask for help on how to approach the troublesome member).

Edited to account for EnergyNumber's comment.  My own experience (mentioned above) was actually with my thesis defense, but I think the advice applies equally well to a thesis proposal, so I've edited my answer to address that (since it was the subject of the question).

Comment: I don't think that the question ist about a thesis defence at the end of the PhD: it's primarily about the proposal defence at the start.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Oh, you're right.  My mistake.  I think most of the advice I gave applies to the proposal too. s/thesis defense/thesis proposal/g;

Answer (score 1):

> What are the key elements that I should include / exclude?

Your university should have clear regulations about that. Also, ask your supervisor/advisor.

> What criteria typically used to judge whether the proposal defense is successful?

So, I'll list a few that should be generally applicable, but if your supervisor feels confident to have you submit your proposal, it's likely you've already met the criteria or close enough to doing so. While the committee can reject your proposal, this isn't like an exam at the end of a course; if you do your work seriously up to the proposal you should pass without surprises. In fact, the defense of the proposal is an opportunity to get useful feedback and guidance.

A few general criteria I believe are always applicable:

- **Novelty** - It must be something that hasn't done before, more than a rehash of existing work. This could be in terms of the results (discovering something we didn't know, creating/manufacturing something which had not previously been attainable) or the methods (e.g. using a novel technique to prove an important mathematical theorem).
- **Relevance** - Your work on efficient separation of mud cakes by the time spent in the sun might not be useful to anyone even if it's novel. This criterion may degenerate into "fashionability" - hopefully not.
- **Expected breadth of work** - The research should involve enough work to be significant but not too much as to risk you not concluding it even with reasonable diligence. Of course, you might eventually be able to get it all done in a week if you're a genius and it's theory rather than experiments; but that's not likely.
- **Your background** - Is it reasonable to assume you personally will be able to carry out this kind of research?
- **Means and environment** - are your supervisor, research group, faculty, university and related facilities and resources likely to be sufficient support for you to pursue your line of research effectively?

> Are the committee's feedback of the proposal typically used as a criteria for the full fledged dissertation defense?

So that really depends on your field and on the composition of the committee. Very often the answer is "no" (from my own personal experience it was "not at all"), but it's certainly possible.

Note, however, that if your results get published in journals and conferences, the final dissertation is, again, unlikely to be rejected - since the community will already have recognized your contribution.